# How to convert SimpleStringProperty object to XML with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I use JAXB (**Java Architecture for XML Binding**) convert `Java` object to  `XML` file

```
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MetaListWrapper.class);
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
               m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    // Wrapping my data.   
    MetaListWrapper wrapper = new MetaListWrapper();
                    wrapper.setTree(sectionList);
    // Marshalling and saving XML to the file.
              m.marshal(wrapper, file);
```

This is my Wrapper:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "metadata")
public class MetaListWrapper {

    private List<Section> sectionList;

    @XmlElement(name = "sectionList")
    public List<Section> getTree() {
        return sectionList;
    }

    public void setTree(List<Section> sectionList) {
        this.sectionList = sectionList;
    }

}
```

And this is Section object:

```
public class Section {

    List<Theme> themes;
    private SimpleStringProperty name, description;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name.toString();
    }

    public List<Theme> getThemes() {
        return themes;
    }

    public void setThemes(List<Theme> themes) {
        this.themes = themes;
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(SimpleStringProperty name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(SimpleStringProperty description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

When I use `private String name, description;` in the object (Section and Theme) `JAXB` extract `XML` normally. `XML` look like this:

```
<sectionList>
     <name>Section 1</name>
    <themes>
         <name>Theme 1</name>
    </themes>
</sectionList>
```

But when I use `private SimpleStringProperty name, description;` return null; and `XML` look like this:

```
<sectionList>
    <name/>
    <themes>
        <name/>
    </themes>
</sectionList>\
```

I must use `SimpleStringProperty` in the project. Whats wrong? How can I extract `SimpleStringProperty` to `XML`?

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4148221/4105457) could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your methods are defined incorrectly.  Look at the javadoc for any JavaFX class and you will see the correct way to do it.

Consider, for example, the [Circle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Circle.html) class:

```
private final DoubleProperty radius = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

public DoubleProperty radiusProperty() {
    return radius;
}

public double getRadius() {
    return radius.get();
}

public void setRadius(double value) {
    radius.set(value);
}
```

(The above is a simplified approximation and is not taken from the actual source for that class.)

Under no circumstances should a get-method return a Property.  Under no circumstances should a set-method take a Property argument.

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks for help. Worked!  I forgot this way.